# Apply AND condition at join in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Hello I have query in which I have to apply and condition in join place, But I don't know how to do this in zend. Please help.

```
$dbA = $this->dbAdapter;
        $sql = new Sql($dbA);
        $select = $sql->select()->from(array('answer' => 'tblanswer'));
        $select->columns($fetch);
        $select->join(array('fixed' => 'tblfixanswer'), 'fixed.aid = answer.aid', array(), 'left');
        $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
        $results = $dbA->query($selectString, $dbA::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

The desired out needed to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tblanswer` AS `answer`
LEFT JOIN `tblfixanswer` AS `fixed` ON `fixed`.`aid` = `answer`.`aid` and fixed.baid=27
```

The value 27 is coming from a variable.

Comment: Thank you Ronak,I have applied your way but the value 27 is coming from a variable so showing like quote like this: AND fixed.baid='27'

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that as,

```
dbA = $this->dbAdapter;
    $sql = new Sql($dbA);
    $select = $sql->select()->from(array('answer' => 'tblanswer'));
    $select->columns($fetch);
    $select->join(array('fixed' => 'tblfixanswer'), 'fixed.aid = answer.aid AND fixed.baid=27', array(), 'left');
    $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
    $results = $dbA->query($selectString, $dbA::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thank you Ronak,I have applied your way but the value 27 is coming from a variable so showing like quote like this: AND fixed.baid='27'

Comment: Yeah but still not coming complete answer, please consider the condition that I have mentioned.

Comment: oh that was question !, you can use fixed.baid="$variable" instead of fixed.baid='27'

Comment: I have written like this but still having showing 27 under quote...
'fixed.aid = answer.aid  AND fixed.baid='."$requester"

Comment: try "fixed.aid = answer.aid AND fixed.baid=$variable", mind the quotes

Comment: $select->join(array('fixed' => 'tblfixanswer'), "fixed.aid = answer.aid AND fixed.baid=$requester", array(), 'left');

Comment: well it's weird, you can try $requester=(int)$requester; at top , and try various combination of quotes.

Comment: tried that and intval also but not helping, to run the code for now I am replacing the string '27' with 27 using str_replace. Let me know if you get the answer... thx btw...